# Access denied for file to download

Tags: asp.net, iis, download

I've published a web site with a root folder called "Content" and containing other folders with images and KML files. Those files are created on the server from the application. File upload for the images and generated for the KML files.

I can download images by getting them using the path `my.web.sit/Content/Images/image.jpg` but I can't access the KML files. Error message is `File or directory not found.`, and if I just write the URL with the folder (no file name), the error is `Forbidden: Access is denied.`.
I tried to add the "location" tag in my root web.config, but no change.

Any idea so I could download these KML files?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your web.config

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.kml" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

> **System.Web.StaticFileHandler** is another internal type that handles access to specified files. In case of access issues it generates one of the following errors: HTTP 401 error "Unauthorized"; HTTP 403 error "Forbidden: Access is denied"; or HTTP 404 error "File or directory not found".

you can see more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bya7fh0a(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Nice try, but it's even worse. Adding these lines to my web.config result in a new error: "500 - Internal server error." I can't event access to my home page any more...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. No particular authorisation were needed, but adding a MIME type.

```html
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".kml" mimeType="text/plain" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope this could help someone !